# Codeiniter After Delete Record Still Show in a Page

Tags: database, codeigniter, caching, anchor

When i delete or update the record and it has been deleted in database but still show when i click on the where the record show page(by anchor) but when i refresh this page(by f5) deleted record not show.
Problem is that i don't want to show deleted record on the page by anchor not need f5 pressing for refresh.

Show page by click on this link:

```
<li><a href="<?=site_url('admin_panel/portfolio_category')?>"><span class="side_icon ion-ios7-calendar-outline"></span> Portfolio Categories</a></li>
```

Following the functions are used:

```
function portfolio_category($task="show",$extra=''){
        if($task=="show"){
$parent_catgs = $this->theartvalley_model->show_record("*","portfolio_category","desc");
if( $parent_catgs != false ){
    if(!empty($extra)) $data["status"] = $extra;
    $data["parent_categories"] = $parent_catgs;
    $this->admin_view("portfolio_category",$data);  
} else $this->admin_view("portfolio_category");
        }
else if($task=="delete"){   
            $this->theartvalley_model->delete_record($id,"portfolio_category");
            redirect(site_url('admin_panel/portfolio_category/show'), 'refresh');
            }   
    }
function show_record($select,$table,$order='asc'){
    $this->db->select($select);
    $this->db->order_by("id", $order); 
    $record = $this->db->get($table);
    if($record->num_rows() > 0){
        $data = $record->result();
        return $data;
        }
    else return false;  
    }  
function delete_record($id,$table){
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->delete($table); 
        }
```

Comment: Where do you grab `$id` from when deleting through `portfolio_category/delete`?

Comment: As your code shows is it refreshing the page on delete of record ?

Comment: how to refreshing?

Comment: #Tpojka <a href="<?=site_url('admin_panel/portfolio_category_modify/delete/'.$id)?>" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a> </div>